# DNS cache issues

Tags: web-services, caching, dns

Here is my issue.

After i build a website. 
I change DNS on the client's url.
Takes few hours for the new site to come up and then few days later the old site would come up for the client for some time and than it switches back to the new website.
This has happened multiple times to multiple clients.

Any ideas whats causing this.(I'm using Godaddy server).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a caching issue, it will solve itself when domain's records will expire from caches.

You'll have to check that your nameservers are configured properly and DNS information it's consistent (all nameservers should have the same serial and identical information about your domain). Use one of the online DNS validation tools to check your domain.

Answer (score 0):

As above, this is most likely a caching issue. You can debug this using Open DNS and online proxy services.

Use OpenDNS to bypass your local ISP.
http://www.opendns.com/
Add their DNS IPs to your list of DNS servers to check (in Mac OS X, Settings > Network > Advanced)
Then use the cachecheck to clear their records of the domain in question (http://www.opendns.com/support/cache/). You should then be able to see the correct site/content. This is the way to tell if a migration has worked, other DNS systems will clear within about 24 hrs.

Also, if you plan to move a domain in the future, consider changing the TTL (time to live) setting to something smaller before the move. Most DNS servers will respect this setting and cache their records of your domain for less time.